# Fastest way to compare neighboring elements in multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: numpy

What is the fastest way to compare neighboring elements in a 3-dimensional array?

Assume I have a numpy array of (4,4,4).  I want to loop in the k-direction and compare elements in pairs.  So, compare all neighboring elements and assign the lowest index if they are not equal.  Essentially this:

```
if array([0, 0, 0)] != array[(0, 0, 1)]:
    array[(0, 0, 0)] = 111
```

Thus, the comparisons would be:

```
(0, 0, 0) and (0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1) and (0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 2) and (0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 3) and (0, 0, 4)
... for all i and j ...
```

However, I want to do this for every i and j in the array and writing a standard Python for loop for this on huge arrays with millions of cells is incredibly slow.  Is there a more 'standard' numpy way to do this without the explicit for loop?

Maybe there's some trick using the slicing step (i.e `array[:,:,::2], array[:,:,1::2]`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `np.diff`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
A = np.array([a, a, a + 1]).T

same_with_neighbor_on_last_axis = np.diff(A, axis=-1) == 0

print A
print same_with_neighbor_on_last_axis
```

A is constructed to have 2 consecutive equal entries along the third axis,

```
>>>print A
array([[[0, 0, 1],
        [3, 3, 4],
        [6, 6, 7]],

       [[1, 1, 2],
        [4, 4, 5],
        [7, 7, 8]],

       [[2, 2, 3],
        [5, 5, 6],
        [8, 8, 9]]])
```

The output vector then yields

```
>>>print same_with_neighbor_on_last_axis
[[[ True False]
  [ True False]
  [ True False]]

 [[ True False]
  [ True False]
  [ True False]]

 [[ True False]
  [ True False]
  [ True False]]]
```

Using the `axis` keyword, you can choose whichever axis you need to do this operation on. If it is all of them, you can use a loop. `np.diff` does not much else than the following

```
np.diff(A, axis=-1) == A[..., 1:] - A[..., :-1]
```

Comment: I think that would work.  However, I'm dealing with large arrays 3-dimensions and 5 million + elements.  So, this seems like it will use a lot of extra memory.  Is this right?

Comment: Ideally I want something like ediff1d that I can loop over for only a single dimension.  Maybe this is possible...I'll think about it a bit more.

Comment: Well, your output will by almost as large as your input, but this is by construction, because that is what you are asking for, if I understand correctly. Other than that, no overhead.

Comment: Yes you're right.  I mention I would like to avoid making a copy of the data.  I think your solution will work, just trying to wrap my head around it.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: I am not completely sure I understand what you mean. If you need to do this 'for all i, j', then your answer will be almost as big as your input.

Comment: Yes, I want to change the array in place though.  I might not have been clear about that in my post.  I want to change every value that is not equal to the value directly next to it.

Comment: You can avoid this copy by doing `B = A[:, :, 1:]` (no copy here, just a view), then `B -= A[:, :, :-1]`. This overwrites your original array and you will find zeros at all positions where there is equality between neighbors.

Comment: That is non-trivial without copying in order to create a mask. But you could do this by blocks such that the mask that you create fits in memory.

Comment: Ah, that might work even better.  I'll have to performance test it and see if it makes sense with the algorithm I end up with when all is said and done.  Thanks again.